# SSAS Tabular date field with multiple category values for current Year, current Month

Tags: ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I'm using Azure Analysis Services. I have a date dimension and I have a couple fields for `IsCurrentYear`, `IsCurrentMonth` and others. They work well but looking to improve.

However, is it possible to have just one field `DateFilter` that has a dynamic list of values.
This `DateFilter` would have values

- Current Year
- Current Month
- Current Week
- Current Quarter
- Last 7 days
- Last 30 days
- could be many more..

I know I could create 8 new fields but if it can be done with one field, that would be a lot simpler and easier to add/remove values.

Unfortunately, I can't just use a C`AS`E statement (it would just pick up the first condition (`Last 7 days` but not `Current year`)

Comment: In SSAS Multidimensional, they have the concept of Sets, which would solve this. But nothing in Tabular Model

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to solve a problem in the database that should be solved in the reporting layer.

Power BI, for example, has a "Relative Date" slicer that does exactly what you are looking for against a Date column.
[image]
[image]

Here are all the choices on the dropdowns:
[image]

Here's where you configure the slicer for Relative Date:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
In Excel, you can add a "Timeline" slicer to a PivotTable:
[image]

Or relative date filters on a table:
[image]

Comment: This is for Excel where our team does their analysis. I haven't seen anything like that here. 
In SSAS Multidimensional, they have the concept of Named Sets, which would solve this. But nothing in Tabular Model

Comment: Hmm, I guess there is Filter on Row Labels in Excel which could work. Still not as clean as Named Sets in Excel.

Comment: Added Excel options above